# How to make a graph form imported spreadsheet data

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

I've three csv files:
v.csv for vertex data, like this: 
1
2
3
...

e.csv for edges:
1,2 
2,4
2,24
3,1
...

and vcoor.csv for vertex coordinates:
23.4, 35.2
23.4, 40.3
...

I know how to construct a simple graph in *Mathematica*, but after importing edges by `Import`, I can't use them in `Graph`

```
v = Import["C:\\Users\\MST\\Desktop\\v.csv", "List"];
e = Import["C:\\Users\\MST\\Desktop\\e.csv", "Table"];
vcoor = Import["C:\\Users\\MST\\Desktop\\vcoor.csv", "Table"];
g = Graph[v, e, VertexCoordinates -> vcoor];
```

Comment: Please show exactly what you tried so far.

Comment: We do *not* have your data,  so unless you provide fully functional code and data to reproduce the problem we will probably not be able to help you.

Comment: CSV files must be imported as `"CSV"`, not as `"Table"`.   Have you looked at what `e` looks like after importing?  Does it have a structure suitable for `Graph`?  Did you look up `Graph` in the documentation to see what form of input it accepts?  It must be an edge list, i.e. if you have `e={{1,2},{3,4}}` you must use `UndirectedEdge @@@ e`.

Comment: Files is too big to upload and can't be truncated, and I know there is no problem in my data. The main problem is Graph function does not accept table (two column matrix) for edges/VertextCoordinates, and I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Very thanks to @Szabolcs! I'm MATLAB coder and I'm new to Mathematica. I read documentation, but I could not find a way to build the edge list form table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the table option in your Import. 
Then, write:

```
g = Graph[v, UndirectedEdge@@@ e, VertexCoordinates -> vcoor]
```

Comment: Sorry, had not refreshed and missed Szabolcs comment. Disregard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about VertexCoordinates? It will be imported from another csv and is not a list

Comment: With the Table options, each line seems to be imported as a single string and not 2 numbers. To see that: vcoor//InputForm

Answer (score 2):

**Input**

```
(*arbitrary data*)
vertices = Range[10];
edges = #1 <-> #2 & @@@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 2}];
coordinates = RandomReal[{1, 50}, {10, 2}];
```

**Process**

```
(*process*)
Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> coordinates]
```

**Output**

[image: output image]

**Reference**

[# & @ @@ etc.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)
[Graph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html)
[Range](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html)
[RandomReal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html)
[RandomInteger](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html)